# SQL aliases on join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *, oc_category.image AS category_image 
FROM oc_product p 
   LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd 
      ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
   LEFT JOIN uploaded_codes uc 
      ON p.product_id = uc.product_id 
   INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc 
      ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id 
   INNER JOIN oc_category c 
      ON ptc.category_id = c.category_id 
   INNER JOIN oc_category_description cd 
      ON cd.category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE pd.language_id = '2' 
   AND pd.name LIKE '%ч%' 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY pd.name ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

Both the product and category tables have an `image` column in them and when it returns the results the category image overwrites the product image. How can I put an alias on the category image so it can come as `category_image` and the product one as `image`?

The following example which I tried returns an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: Unknown column
>   'oc_category.image' in 'field list

Comment: You aliased `oc_category` as `c`.. so select `c.image as category_image`

Comment: When I get them in php
I get an array with image key in it and it holds tha value for the category image

Comment: But in the query your using your selecting everything from oc_product and. I can not see anything about the product image. Your not fetching the product image. Could you provide us an example data with the desired result?

Comment: Well, it simply seems like the problem is your use of  `SELECT *`, where the `image` column is appearing multiple times. It's best that you list every column you need **explicitely**: `SELECT p.col1, .....`

Comment: @Lamak thats the right answer. Like i told he is selecting columns under different names which is confusing. Try to avoid SELECT *

Comment: @TheAngelM97 Ah, yeah.. As Lamak said, you should list your columns.  Just for simple verification, make your select: `SELECT p.image, c.image as category_image`

Comment: This query is nonsensical, so it's hard to know where you want to go with it. instead, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you already gave an alias to the `oc_category` table, you should use it. And use backticks for reserved words in columns:

```
SELECT *, c.`image` AS category_image 
FROM oc_product p 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd 
    ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN uploaded_codes uc 
    ON p.product_id = uc.product_id 
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc 
    ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id 
INNER JOIN oc_category c 
    ON ptc.category_id = c.category_id 
INNER JOIN oc_category_description cd 
    ON cd.category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE pd.language_id = '2' 
AND pd.name LIKE '%ч%' 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY pd.name ASC LIMIT 0,20;
```

Comment: Where are the reserved words?

Comment: there is no cateogry_image and the image is overwritten by the category's image

Comment: @TheAngelM97 I'm sorry...what?, I don't really understand your comment

Comment: @Strawberry well, I don't actually use mysql, so I assumed that `image` might be a reserved word. In any case, the backticks shouldn't affect the result

Comment: I receive the results in php
And i has an array with image key and it holds the value for the category image but I want it to hold the value for the product image and the key for the category image to be category_image. The change you told me to make does not work

Comment: @TheAngelM97 read my other comment to you. You need to list your columns explicitely, instead of simply using `SELECT *`

Comment: OK, It isn't. But even if it was, the `c.` would preclude the need for backticks.

Comment: Of greater concern, is the use of the evil 'SELECT *' and the provision of a GROUP BY clause in the absence of any aggregating functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given alias "c" to table "oc_category", change `oc_category.image` in select terms to `c.image`.

Comment: Now the error is gone but there's no category_image and the image is overwritten again